# Ordering vertices in GraphPlot

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I'm new here, so forgive me if this question is not well-posed/duplicates an earlier question - although I've searched for similar questions without success.

I'm trying to present a plot of connections between elements (correlations between student performance on a set of test questions, actually). It's something like (with options omitted):

```
test = {{1 -> 5, 1}, {4 -> 3, 3.6}, {6 -> 8, 1}, {2 -> 4, 2}, {2 -> 5,
     2.5}, {5 -> 4, 0.9}, {7 -> 8, 2}, {3 -> 8, 1}, {8 -> 2, 1}};
GraphPlot[test, Method -> "CircularEmbedding", VertexLabeling -> True,
  EdgeLabeling -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

where the {1,2,3,...} are the labels for my questions.

I want to order the vertices in ascending order  (1,2,3,...), i.e. I want vertices with consecutive labels to be adjacent on the circle, like a clock - i.e. as in the image below, which I had to construct by making the connections more or less consecutive:

```
test2 = {{1 -> 2, 1}, {3 -> 4, 3.6}, {5 -> 6, 1}, {7 -> 8, 
2}, {2 -> 5, 2.5}, {5 -> 4, 0.9}, {7 -> 3, 2}, {3 -> 8, 
1}, {8 -> 2, 1}};
GraphPlot[test2, Method -> "CircularEmbedding", VertexLabeling -> True, EdgeLabeling -> False]
```

[image: graphics2]

Mathematica has its own ideas! It insists on ordering the vertices by the order in which it encounters them in the list of connections, (i.e. 1,5,4,3,...) in the above example. Sorting the list of connections doesn't fix this problem. This issue doesn't seem to be well documented. Any suggestions for a workaround?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! Please edit your post to include a working sample of `test` so the community can fool around with that.

Comment: Could you also elaborate a bit on how your result should look like? I do not get it yet - although others may ;-). If you get another upvote you´ll be able to post images etc. as well.

Comment: Edited. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Are disconnected components allowed (this would affect my answer...)?

Comment: Yes, disconnected components are allowed - I need it to be robust and general

Comment: Can you use `Graph` function?

Comment: Welcome to MMA SE! Ooku. I would suggest that you wait a reasonable amount of time (3-4 days), before accepting any given answer. This is because:SE members are located worldwide and so live in different time zones. The best answers might need a bit to be written and people are more motivated if they see that you have not yet accepted any previous answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way would be to define `VertexCoordinateRules`.

First, we extract a sorted list of all your vertices:

```
myVertices = Sort[Union[Flatten[{test[[All, 1, 1]], test[[All, 1, 2]]}]]];
```

Then, we use `CircularEmbedding` from the `Combinatorica` package to construct a list of equally spaced points on a circle that we'll use for the `VertexCoordinateRules`:

```
<< Combinatorica`
coords = Table[myVertices[[i]] -> 
    Partition[Flatten[CircularEmbedding[Length[myVertices]]], 2][[i]], {i, 
    Length[myVertices]}]
```

And the plot:

```
GraphPlot[test, VertexLabeling -> True, 
    EdgeLabeling -> False, VertexCoordinateRules -> coords]
```

[image]

A case with disconnected components:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

You can get what you need with `Graph` easily if `GraphPlot` is not otherwise essential for your application. Like  `GraphPlot`, `Graph` takes the list of vertices as they appear in the list of edges if a list of vertices is not provided, but, unlike `GraphPlot`, it also accepts the list of vertices as an argument.

With a few lines to almost replicate the rendering you get in `GraphPlot`:

```
(* vertex shape function with labels *)
vsh[{xc_, yc_}, name_, {w_, h_}] := {Red, Rectangle[{xc - w, yc - h},
  {xc + w, yc + h}], Inset[Style[Text[name], 14, White, Bold], {xc, yc}]};
options =  Sequence[VertexSize -> 0.1, VertexShapeFunction -> vsh, 
  GraphLayout -> "CircularEmbedding", ImageSize -> 300];

g1 = Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 5, 3 -> 1, 3 -> 2, 4 -> 5, 4 -> 2}, options];
g2 = Graph[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1 -> 2, 2 -> 5, 3 -> 1, 3 -> 2, 4 -> 5, 4 -> 2}, options];
g3 = Graph[{5, 1, 4, 3, 2}, {1 -> 2, 2 -> 5, 3 -> 1, 3 -> 2, 4 -> 5, 4 -> 2}, options];
Grid[{{Row[{"VertexList[g1] = ", VertexList[g1]}], 
       Row[{"VertexList[g2] = ", VertexList[g2]}], 
       Row[{"VertexList[g3] = ", VertexList[g3]}]},
       {g1, g2, g3}}, 
       Alignment -> Center]
```

[image]

**Update:** In case you "have to" use `GraphPlot`, here is an alternative approach that extracts the vertex coordinates of your graph and remaps the vertices to these coordinates:

```
options2 = Sequence[Method -> "CircularEmbedding", VertexLabeling -> True, 
       EdgeLabeling -> False, ImageSize -> 300];
vertexlist =  First /@ (test /. Rule -> List) // Flatten // DeleteDuplicates;
(* your original graph *)
gp1 = GraphPlot[test, options2];
(* get the vertex coordinates of gp1 and remap the vertices to these coordinates *)
newvcr = Thread[ Range[Length[vertexlist]] -> 
       First@Cases[gp1, Rule[VertexCoordinateRules, x_] :> x, {0, Infinity}]];
Row[{gp1, GraphPlot[test, options2, VertexCoordinateRules -> newvcr]}, Spacer[5]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

**EDIT**: Incorporating @VLC´s suggestion concerning disconnected components...

Perhaps this can help you as a starting point (using a supplemented test set):

```
test = {{1 -> 5, 1}, {4 -> 3, 3.6}, {6 -> 8, 1}, {2 -> 4, 2}, {2 -> 5,
       2.5}, {5 -> 4, 0.9}, {7 -> 8, 2}, {3 -> 8, 1}, {8 -> 2, 
      1}, {9 -> 10, 1}, {13 -> 13, 1}, {17 -> 2, 1}} // Sort // 
   Reverse;

vertices = Union[test[[All, 1]] /. Rule -> List // Flatten ];

coords = MapIndexed[#1 -> {Sin[
       2 Pi (#2[[1]] - 1)/Length[vertices]], 
      Cos[2 Pi (#2[[1]] - 1)/Length[vertices]]} &, vertices];

GraphPlot[test, VertexLabeling -> True, EdgeLabeling -> False, 
 VertexCoordinateRules -> coords]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

One approach might be to extract the `VertexCoordinateRules` from an appropiate `GraphPlot` (for example from {1->2, 2-> 3, 3-> 4 ...}) using `Cases`, and use these to order the vertices in the graph of interest.

For example

```
ceRules[noVertices_, offset_: 0] := 
 MapThread[Rule, {RotateLeft[Range[noVertices], offset], #}] &@
  Cases[GraphPlot[Rule @@@ Partition[Range[noVertices], 2, 1], 
     VertexLabeling -> True, 
     Method -> "CircularEmbedding"], (VertexCoordinateRules -> x_) :> 
     x, Infinity][[1]]
```

Or, to obtain the vertices in a clockwise order

```
ceRulesCW[noVertices_, offset_: 0] := 
 MapThread[
    Rule, {Reverse@RotateLeft[Range[noVertices], offset], #}] &@
  Cases[GraphPlot[Rule @@@ Partition[Range[noVertices], 2, 1], 
     VertexLabeling -> True, 
     Method -> "CircularEmbedding"], (VertexCoordinateRules -> x_) :> 
     x, Infinity][[1]]
```

With

```
test = {{1 -> 5, 1}, {4 -> 3, 3.6}, {6 -> 8, 1}, {2 -> 4, 2}, {2 -> 5,
     2.5}, {5 -> 4, 0.9}, {7 -> 8, 2}, {3 -> 8, 1}, {8 -> 2, 1}};
```

the following may be obtained:

```
Grid@{GraphPlot[test, VertexLabeling -> True, EdgeLabeling -> False, 
     VertexCoordinateRules -> #] & /@ {ceRules[8, -4], 
    ceRulesCW[8, -3]}}
```

[image: Two GraphPlots with vertices numbered clockwise & anticlockwise]

For example:

```
ceRules@10
```

> {1 -> {3.23607, 1.53884}, 2 -> {2.92705, 2.4899}, 
>    3 -> {2.11803, 3.07768}, 4 -> {1.11803, 3.07768},
>
> 5 -> {0.309017, 2.4899}, 6 -> {0., 1.53884}, 
>    7 -> {0.309017, 0.587785},
>
> 8 -> {1.11803, 1.3469*10^-10}, 
>    9 -> {2.11803, 0.}, 10 -> {2.92705, 0.587785}}