# Ordering vertices with minimum Edge Crossing in Circular Graphs

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Weighted and sorted *Mathematica* circular graphs are shown below. My question is how to reorder the vertices in such a way that they have **minimum cuts** (intersection of edges) while keeping the circular graph in shape.

Some useful links to `GraphPlot`, circular graph and `EdgeRenderingFunction` for edge thickness from Mathematica.StackExchange and StackOverflow:

- [Ordering vertices in `GraphPlot`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10755/125)
- [Removing edge weights from a graph](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5618/removing-edge-weights-from-a-graph?rq=1)
- [Label edges with their weights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381085/how-to-label-graph-edges-with-their-weights)
- [Graph layout that reflects edge weights](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4520/how-to-get-graph-layout-that-reflects-edge-weights?rq=1)

Mathematica code:

```
(*vertex shape function with labels*)
options = 
  Sequence[Method -> "CircularEmbedding", VertexLabeling -> True, 
   EdgeLabeling -> False,
   EdgeRenderingFunction -> ({Text[Style[#3, 15], Mean[#1]],
       Blue, AbsoluteThickness[0.8 + #3/5],
       Arrowheads[0.02 + #3/170],
       Arrow[#1, 0.075]} &), ImageSize -> 200];
```

Default *Mathematica* circular graph arranges vertices differently.

```
(*default mathematica circular graph*)
connections = {{1 -> 5, 1}, {4 -> 3, 3.6}, {6 -> 8, 1}, {2 -> 4, 
    2}, {2 -> 5, 2.5}, {5 -> 4, 0.9}, {7 -> 8, 2}, {3 -> 8, 
    1}, {8 -> 2, 1}};
gp1 = GraphPlot[connections, options];
```

So, we need to sort circular graph vertices to start calculating minumum cut (intersecting edges).

```
(*sorted mathematica circular graph*)
Needs["Combinatorica`"];
sortedVertices = 
  Sort[Union[
    Flatten[{connections[[All, 1, 1]], connections[[All, 1, 2]]}]]];
sortedConnections = Table[
   sortedVertices[[i]] -> 
    Partition[Flatten[CircularEmbedding[Length[sortedVertices]]], 2][[i]],
   {i, Length[sortedVertices]}];
gp2 = GraphPlot[connections, options, 
   VertexCoordinateRules -> sortedConnections];
(*show two graphs*)
Row[{gp1, gp2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The question is how the above code can be rearranged in such a way that `GraphPlot` has **minimum cuts** (intersection of edges) while keeping the circular graph in shape. The vertex points order may be changed but not the number of connections or directions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After some investigation I come up with some below listed links that might be useful.

According to Michael Baur and Ulrik Brandes in paper
['Crossing Reduction in Circular Layouts'](https://i11www.iti.kit.edu/extra/publications/bb-crcl-04_TR.pdf):

Circular crossing minimization is NP-hard problem. On the other hand, a graph has a circular layout with no crossings, if and only if it is outerplanar. A linear time recognition algorithm for outerplanar graphs can easily extended to yield a crossing free circular layout.Since, in particular, trees have circular layouts with no crossings, it is possible to consider the biconnected components of a graph separately, and insert their circular layouts into a crossing free layout of the block-cutpoint-tree without producing additional crossings. See figure below for an illustration.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Other related works are:

- [Algorithm - Optimum Linear Arrangement](https://drum.lib.umd.edu/bitstream/handle/1903/4503/TR_86-80.pdf)
- [Algorithm - Circular](https://www.csd.uoc.gr/%7Ehy583/reviewed_notes/circular.pdf)
- [Algorithm - Circular Sifting - Crossing Minimization in Extended Level Drawings of Graphs](https://www.infosun.fim.uni-passau.de/%7Echris/down/ExtendedCrossingReduction.pdf)
- [Crossing Reduction in Circular Layouts](https://i11www.iti.kit.edu/extra/publications/bb-crcl-04_TR.pdf)
- [Circular Drawings of Biconnected Graphs](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-48518-X_4)
- [Handbook of Graph Drawing and Visualization (nice online ref)](https://web.archive.org/web/20180426215228/http://cs.brown.edu:80/%7Ert/gdhandbook/)
- [Circular Drawing Algorithms](https://web.archive.org/web/20220213184937/http://cs.brown.edu/people/rtamassi/gdhandbook/chapters/circular.pdf)