# Most efficient way to output a cycle starting from an unordered list of graph vertices

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I have some graph $G$ and a list of vertices $(v_1, ..., v_N) \in V$.  Using graph structures in Mathematica version 9.0, what is the most efficient way to determine whether or not $(v_1, ..., v_N)$ represents a cycle, and then, if so, to output a permutation cycle starting from some desired $v_i$?

---

Let me provide a specific example:

Say I have a ring of eight vertices where:

$v_1 \to v_2$

$v_2 \to v_3$

$v_3 \to v_4$

$v_4 \to v_5$

$v_5 \to v_6$

$v_6 \to v_7$

$v_7 \to v_8$

$v_8 \to v_1$

And also:

$v_2 \to v_4$

$v_4 \to v_6$

$v_6 \to v_8$

$v_8 \to v_2$

Say the above list is scrambled (i.e. we randomly assign the vertex labels).  Without scrambling things here, and specifying that I want a permutation to start from $v_2$, how would I output a permutation:

$(v_2,v_3,v_4,v_5,v_6,v_7,v_8,v_1)$

Scrambling, we could maybe map the labels: $(v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4, v_5, v_6, v_7, v_8)$ to something like: $(v_{1111111111}, v_{11011}, v_{111110011}, v_{100101}, v_{11}, v_{1010111}, v_{111}, v_{101010101})$ where the labels convey no ordering information.

Comment: you can check the link about *Ordering vertices in GraphPlot* http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10755/ordering-vertices-in-graphplot

Comment: Is your graph directed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am reading your question correctly, you are looking for

```
HamiltonianGraphQ@Subgraph[g, {v1, v2, ...}]
```

You can use `FindHamiltonianCycle` to actually find a cycle (an ordering of vertices).

Comment: Please let me know if I misunderstood.

Comment: Right, calling "FindHamiltonianCycle" solves my problem, though I have a special very easy case of what would otherwise by an NP-complete problem.  I suppose I could also cut the connections between a pair of vertices $v_i$ and $v_j$ and then run "FindShortestPath".

Comment: Note that `FindHamiltonianCycle` is not necessarily slow ("bad" complexity).  It is slow for some input graphs, but it isn't for a cycle graph.

Comment: I think I should be able to make my set of vertices a cycle...  Do we know the time complexity for "FindHamiltonianCycle" on a cycle graph?

Comment: @Roget I don't know how it is implemented, but it makes sense to assume that it is linear complexity (in the number of nodes).  There aren't that many ways to traverse a cycle graphs.  If you want to make sure, you can measure directly.

Comment: I think we can just call "FindEulerianCycle" instead of "FindHamiltonianCycle" if we want to use something that everyone knows has linear time solution (if something like Hierholzer's algorithm is being used) or an "almost linear time" solution... which will depend on the exact implementation.

Comment: Well, you know what you need ... I thought you wanted to avoid the same node being visited twice, which FindEulerianCycle may not.  If you're concerned about performance, *measure*!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to verify a given list of vertices is a cycle, you could define the following function to check it's cycle:

```
cycleQ[g_, vs_] :=
      Block[{edge},
          edge = If[DirectedGraphQ[g], DirectedEdge, UndirectedEdge];
          VectorQ[Partition[vs, 2, 1, 1], EdgeQ[g, edge @@ #] &]
      ]
```

For example,

```
g = CycleGraph[10];

In[96]:= cycleQ[g, Range[5]]
Out[96]= False

In[97]:= cycleQ[g, Range[10]]
Out[97]= True
```

To permute the list, you could use RotateLeft or RotateRight with Position:

```
In[91]:= RotateLeft[{a, b, c, d, e}, 
             Position[{a, b, c, d, e}, d][[1, 1]] - 1]
Out[91]= {d, e, a, b, c}
```

Comment: Thanks, the CycleQ[...] function addresses the first part of my question!

Comment: However, let's say the vertices are unordered and not necessarily just connected to their nearest-neighbors in the cycle (i.e. vertex $i$ could be connected to vertex $j$ and $j+1$, etc.).  We are only guaranteed that there is a unique solution for the cycle that only uses each vertex once.  How would we output a cycle permutation?